# can not create db_schema_whitelist.json file in magento 2.4.4

Tags: php, mysql, magento2.4

I have issue to create custom mysql table from xml schema.

i have create app/code/Vendor_Name/Module_Name/etc/db_schema.xml

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="test_table" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Test blog table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true"
                comment="Entity ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" length="70" nullable="false" comment="Title"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_at" on_update="false" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                comment="Creation Time"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="updated_at" on_update="true" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                comment="Update Time"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
   </table>
</schema>
```

After this i have execute CLI with no error but can't create db_schema_whitelist.json in ***Vendor_Name/Module_name/etc*** folder

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=VendorName_ModuleName
```

My vendor_Name/Module_Name is already ***enable***

What i do please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I use your db_schema.xml and run below command for create db_schema_whitelist.json

> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
> --module-name=MagentoCoders_SizeChart

As per CLI command for whitelist

> php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
> --module-name=VendorName_ModuleName

and I successfully generated db_schema_whitelist.json file in magento 2.4.4.
Please, find out db_schema_whitelist file attachment

[CLI COMMAND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgN1g.png)

[db_schema_whitelist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IP5N.png)

[db_schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7tLX.png)